# DSpace 7.6, IIIF and restricted collection -Does it Work?

Tags: dspace, iiif, mirador

My DSpace 7.6 public web server uses the Mirador IIIF image viewer in all the public areas. I just attempted to create a private community for a client. I cannot get the IIIF Mirador viewer to work inside a restricted Community/Collection/Item.

The private community/collection is restricted to my defined group and users can access the restricted items and read the metadata and download bitstreams (as expected).
I enable dspace.iiif.enabled = true in my items but the Mirador viewer box never gets populated with anything (no metadata, no images, no errors). I see only an empty outline.

I have a difficult time understanding DSpace's Authorization policies and the proper methods to use in creating a Private Community, Collection and items. I am not sure if the Mirador viewer and IIIF has even been proven to work in this case.
Has anyone used these features successfully?

Would someone be kind enough to show me a procedure?
Everything is running on a single, public web server
DSpace 7.6
Ubuntu 22.04
Cantaloupe 5